# How to reference a photo from the library and sync it between devices?

Tags: swift, core-data, photo-picker, photosui

I am using `PHPickerViewController` to select a photo from the photo library. Once it returns a `PHPickerResult` I have been storing the `assetIdentifier` from it in CoreData, so that I can reference that photo again without having to copy the photo into my CoreData store. This works great until I sync the CoreData store between devices with CloudKit.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible, and if so what is the reference that I should be using between devices?

Comment: There is no cross device identifier. There is no guarantee that the item even exists on another device